# Install VLC on offline ubuntu

Tags: vlc, offline

i have 32 bit ubuntu 12.04 on an offline computer. I can access the internet using a different windows 7 computer and i have a memory key. How do i install vlc on my offline ubuntu computer?

Answer (score 2):

You can download it to your windows 7 computer using **[Cube](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583)**, it is a portable package manager capable of downloading packages from any computer with internet connection (e.g your windows 7 computer) and install it back to your linux computer.

Here is the complete tutorial on how to use it : http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583

Answer (score 1):

You must download a deb package from http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-debian.html move it to ubuntu and run this by clicking two times
Or use dpkg in terminal.